# How to show that an open map $f $ implies the surjectivity of $f'$ in a dense set

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry

Let $f$ be a $C^1$ map from $U\to \mathbb{R}^m$, where $U$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $n\geq m$. Then we know that if $f'$ is surjective everywhere, then $f$ is open.

My question is whether the converse is valid,  if the answer is no, can we prove the following weaker conclusion:

If $f$ is open, $f'$ is surjective in a dense set of $U$

Comment: $f(x) = x^3$ is open (since strictly increasing), but $f'(0) = 0$ which is not surjective.

Comment: @copper.hat ... but $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ s dense in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: I was just addressing the first question, nothing springs to mind for the second...

Comment: What if $f(z)=z$, $f'(z)=1$? surjective to where?

Comment: @i707107 The derivative $f' = df$ is a linear map $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$. The question asks whether the derivative of an open $C^1$ map has rank $m$ in a dense set of its domain.

Comment: @Martin I see, I have mistaken, took it as complex analytic function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided $f$ is of class $C^k$ for some $k\ge \max(n-m+1,1)$, your weaker conclusion follows from [Sard's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sard%27s_theorem).  Suppose the set $R$ of points where $df$ is surjective (i.e., the set of regular points of $f$) is not dense in $U$.  Then $V = U\setminus \overline{R}$ is a nonempty open subset of $U$.  Since every point of $V$ is a critical point of $f$, Sard's theorem implies that $f(V)$ has measure zero in $\mathbb R^m$, so it cannot be open.

Comment: I interpreted the question to be looking for an example showing in a drastic way that the conclusion of Sard's theorem is sharp. Whitney's example in his famous article [A function not constant on a connected set of critical points](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077489217) does not seem to be good enough since the set of points where it fails to have full rank is an arc, hence its complement is dense.

Answer (score 2):

I expect that the answer is negative when $n>m$; that is, $C^1$ regularity is not enough. An important paper on the subject is *A singular map of a cube onto a square* by Robert Kaufman, J. Differential Geom. 14 (1979), no. 4, 593–594 (1981). In this two-page note Kaufman constructs a $C^1$ map from $[0,1]^3$ onto $[0,1]^2$ whose derivative has rank at most $1$ at every point. Therefore, the set of points where the derivative is surjective is **empty**. A more elaborate construction  by S.M. Bates in [On the image size of singular maps I](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1992-114-03/S0002-9939-1992-1074748-8/home.html) takes Hölder continuity of the derivative into account.

Although in these examples the image of $f$ contains an open subset of $\mathbb R^m$, I do not know if they are, or can be modified into, open maps. A starting point would be to go through the [papers that cite Kaufman's example](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&lr=&cites=15486130190217629763), some of which are very recent.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for this!

Answer (score -1):

If f is defined on na open subset of Rm with values on Rn and is of class C1, then f open implies that f'(x) is surjective on na open and dense subset of U.

Comment: The question is *whether* and, if so, *why* this is true. Can you back up your answer with a reference or a sketch of the argument you have in mind? As it stands, this does not look like an answer to me.