# Open smooth maps have a surjective differential on a dense subset

Tags: real-analysis

I have been reading *The Analysis of Linear Partial Differential Operators I* by L. Hörmander and came about a statement on page 134, right before theorem 6.1.2:

> If $f$ is open then $f'(x)$ is surjective for all $x$ in a dense subset of $X_1$.

To be more precise: The map $f: X_1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a smooth map on an open subset $X_1 \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ and is open in the topological sense. Its Jacobian at x is denoted by $f'(x)$.

The author does not give a justification for this statement, so that I assume that it is common knowledge: From *Sard's theorem* we know that the set of critical values of any smooth map is a null set. If we assume the converse of the hypothesis, i.e. that $f'(x)$ is not surjective in an open ball, it follows that the set of critical values contains an open ball, for $f$ is open, hence the set of critical values cannot be null in contradiction to Sard's theorem.

My question is now: Is there a more direct way to see why this statement must be true, without invoking Sard's theorem?

Comment: That question has been posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366174/how-to-show-that-an-open-map-f-implies-the-surjectivity-of-f-in-a-dense-se) before and the accepted answer used Sard's theorem.